# Python multiprocessing in for loop (requests and BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-requests, multiprocessing

I have list of a lot of links and I want to use multiprocessing to speed the proccess, here is simplified  version, I need it to be ordered like this:

[image: click]

I tried a lot of things, process, pool etc. I always had errors, I need to do it with 4 or 8 threads and make it ordered like this. Thank you for all help. Here is code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

links = ["http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1672704", "http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1699387", "http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1698990" "http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1696623", "http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1688719", "http://www.tennisexplorer.com/match-detail/?id=1686305"]

data = []

def essa(match, omega):
    aaa = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(match).text, "lxml")
    center = aaa.find("div", id="center")
    p1_l = center.find_all("th", class_="plName")[0].find("a").get("href")
    p2_l = center.find_all("th", class_="plName")[1].find("a").get("href")
    return p1_l + " - " + p2_l + " - " + str(omega)

i = 1

start_time = time.clock()

for link in links:
    data.append(essa(link, i))
    i += 1

for d in data:
    print(d)

print(time.clock() - start_time, "seconds")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawn several threads of the function and join them together:

```
from threading import Thread

def essa(match, omega):
    aaa = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(match).text, "lxml")
    center = aaa.find("div", id="center")
    p1_l = center.find_all("th", class_="plName")[0].find("a").get("href")
    p2_l = center.find_all("th", class_="plName")[1].find("a").get("href")
    print p1_l + " - " + p2_l + " - " + str(omega)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threadlist = []
    for index, url in enumerate(links):
        t= Thread(target=essa,args=(url, index))
        t.start()
        threadlist.append(t)
    for b in threadlist:
        b.join()
```

You wont get them to print in order, for the simple reason that some http responses take longer than others.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b6f8ca38c069476cc6522cf7bfaf181e - thank you, it looks pretty barbaric but it works, 50 links with 8 threads in 16 seconds, amazing, with one thread it'd take ~80 seconds! I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @R3FLICK sorry for the barbarism, accept the answer and have fun.

Comment: Could you just let me know how to make variable store the essa function? I need to apply it here: https://gyazo.com/78b854cdd96b49850a8ff33c450d1d7c so for each game in player_2["all"] it makes one thread (up to 8 let's say) and keeps it in variable. THank you for help.

Comment: @R3FLICK Sorry I don't really understand what you mean by that. If you explain it clearly in  another question and post the link to it here I will answer there no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand you have the list of links and make requests concurrently to make the process faster. Here is the sample code for multithreading. I hope this will help you. Read the documentation for concurrent futures.

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```